# Como mantener el color de los elementos de un bloque usando background-image?

Tags: css, css3, scss, selectores-css, css-transform

El problema es que cuando paso el cursor sobre la imagen esta se vuelve opaca afectando a los elementos del titulo, subtitulo y el boton.

Como seria que solo la imagen se vuelva opaca sin afectar a los otros elementos ?

aqui esta mi **html**:

```
<div class="visitanos__contenido">
            <h2 class="visitanos__contenido-title">Visítanos</h2>
            <h3 class="visitanos__contenido-subtitle">
              Todo el año Galería de Arte de Practicum 404, Avenida Tim
              Berners-Lee.
            </h3>
            <button class="visitanos__contenido-boton">Comprar entradas</button>
          </div>
```

Aqui esta mi **CSS** de del contenedor:

```
.visitanos__contenido{
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url(imagenes/__background.png);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
  background-blend-mode: overlay; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Aqui esta el **hover** que utilize lo que pasa esque todos los elementos se vuelven opacos pero solo necesito que la imagen se vuelva opaca sin afectar a los otros elementos como podria lograr esto ?

```
.visitanos__contenido:hover {
  opacity: 0.30000001192092896;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu dices:

> El problema es que cuando paso el cursor sobre la imagen

Es que no pasas el cursor sobre la imagen, lo pasas sobre el contenedor `.visitanos__contenido`, y además la regla del `hover` la tienes sobre ese mismo contenedor.

`.visitanos__contenido` contiene el titulo, el subtitulo, un botón y una imagen de fondo. Si haces opaco un contenedor TODO su contenido se opaca.

Lo que debes hacer es sacar el fondo a otro contenedor, en tu caso, me parece que lo más simple para no modificar la estructura del HTML, es usar un `before`. De manera tal, que todo lo referente al `background` lo movemos a `.visitanos__contenido:before`

Demo

```css
.visitanos__contenido{
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position:relative;
}

.visitanos__contenido:before{
  content:'';
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/536/354);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
  background-blend-mode: overlay; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index:-1;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
    

}

.visitanos__contenido:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.30000001192092896;
}
```

```html
<div class="visitanos__contenido">
  <h2 class="visitanos__contenido-title">Visítanos</h2>
  <h3 class="visitanos__contenido-subtitle">
    Todo el año Galería de Arte de Practicum 404, Avenida Tim
    Berners-Lee.
  </h3>
  <button class="visitanos__contenido-boton">Comprar entradas</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdada

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente, los elementos "hijos" están heredando la propiedad opacity del contenedor. ¿Has probado a asignarle un opacity correcto a los mismos bajo el evento :hover?

Por ejemplo:

```
.visitanos__contenido:hover {
  opacity: 0.30000001192092896;
}

.visitanos__contenido:hover .visitanos__contenido-title{
    opacity: 1; /* para que siga siendo opaco */

}
```